# What does "invalid" means in the conversation given down below?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

(Peter is knocking on Scott's door to pick up his mom to take her out for a dinner)

Peter: Hello there.

(Scott is trying to slam a door in Peter's face)

Peter : Really? Slam the door in my face? Come on, Scott.

Scott : I'll tell her.

Peter : That I used to be a catatonic **invalid**
with burns covering half my face? Good luck with that.

Comment: What has your research shown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably confused due to there being two different words with the same spelling.

**INVALID** (in-VAL-id) means not valid, being without foundation or force in fact, truth, or law

**INVALID** (in-vuh-lid) means a sickly or disabled person, usually with the implication of being a shut-in

Your example uses the second one

Comment: And you should clarify that it is the second definition that is being used here. Peter used to be a handicapped person.

Comment: Good point. Done